# Как в PyCharm отключить "желтую лампочку"

Tags: python, pycharm

Как в PyCharm отключить "желтую лампочку", всплывающую подсказку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно отключить в **Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion**, опция **Auto-display parameter info**. Можно также увеличить задержку перед отображением окошка с подсказкой как вариант.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]